# Many errors on screen. Data table and autocomplete primefaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

My data table does not show exclusion message. I put the id of message on update metod of commandbutton inside of data table, but i receive  `Cannot find component with identifier "messages" referenced from "j_idt31:`

The Autocomplete does not works. error occurs in the name of the converter. I put the name beginning whith upper and lower cases but not works. I receive 
`Jul 29, 2013 4:11:19 PM com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl createConverter
SEVERE: JSF1006: Não pode criar instância para o conversor de tipo pacienteConverter`

```
<ui:define name="conteudo">
    <h:form>
        <p:panelGrid columns="2" id="painel"
            style="width: 100%; margin-top: 20px" columnClasses="rotulo, campo">
            <p:outputLabel value="Nome do paciente" for="nPaciente" />

            <p:autoComplete value="#{cadastroPacienteBean.pacienteSelecionado}" id="nPaciente"
                completeMethod="#{cadastroPacienteBean.pacientes}" var="p"
                itemLabel="#{p.name}" itemValue="#{p}" converter="pacienteConverter"
                forceSelection="true">
                <f:facet name="itemtip">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">                           
                        <h:outputText value="Nome do Paciente: " />
                        <h:outputText  value="#{p.nomePaciente}" />
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </f:facet>
            </p:autoComplete>
        </p:panelGrid>

        <p:messages id="messages" showDetail="false" showSummary="true" />


        <p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="paciente"
            value="#{consultaPacienteBean.pacientes}" paginator="true" rows="10"
            paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
            rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15">


            <p:column sortBy="#{paciente.nomePaciente}"
                headerText="nome do Paciente">

                <h:outputText value="#{paciente.nomePaciente}" />
            </p:column>




            <p:column style="width: 100px; text-align: center">
                <p:button icon="ui-icon-pencil" outcome="CadastroPaciente"
                    title="Editar">
                    <f:param name="codigo" value="#{paciente.codigo}" />
                </p:button>

                <p:commandButton action="#{consultaPacienteBean.excluir}"
                    icon="ui-icon-trash" title="Excluir" update="dataTable,messages"
                    ajax="true">
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener
                        target="#{consultaPacienteBean.pacienteSelecionado}"
                        value="#{paciente}" />

                </p:commandButton>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>


    </h:form>


</ui:define>
```

My class Converter :

```
@FacesConverter(forClass=Paciente.class)
public class PacienteConverter implements Converter {

}
```

Comment: Your question is too broad. Please post one question per question. Please handle one problem per question. Please post the code in SSCCE flavor to reduce code noise. Please do not post code which is completely irrelevant to the problem, like panel grid component, style attribute, etc. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: I think your converter in `p:autoComplete` must be declare : `converter="#{pacienteConverter}"`